# Resource for AWS with Java

Tags: java, spring, amazon-web-services, web

So I have been looking at Spring MVC as a framework and maybe a schema-less DB like Redis, to develop a website from scratch.

I see that AWS (Amazon Web Services), is an ideal solution for me that I will try to use as the host; if things pick up, down the line.

I was hoping someone could point me toward some great resources or books, that may help me in my venture.

Additionally does anyone know if you can dev/design your code base around AWS without actually using it? Sorry if this is a dumb question that doesnt make sense. I am not familiar enough with the process as of yet. I just know I will probably end up hosting my project on a cheaper service before I get it onto the Amazon Services.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are super estimating AWS api complexity, interface and SDK are quite simple and straightforward to implement.

I suggest you starting by downloading [SDK](http://aws.amazon.com/pt/sdkforjava/) of course and than take a look some [samples and the Getting Started](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSdkDocsJava/latest/DeveloperGuide/welcome.html). 
You also can find everything you would need at [AWS Documentation](http://aws.amazon.com/documentation/). 
For testing and practicing I suggest you create an account and use the [Free Tier](http://aws.amazon.com/free/), it is more than enough for learning and costs nothing =].

Comment: Thank you! Your answer is much appreciated! I am relieved to find that there is a Free Tier for all of this!!
So if I am reading this correctly you code through the AWS SDK instead of the Spring MVC framework? Again sorry for the dumb questions, just want to know for clarity's sake.

Comment: You can use both, AWS SDK solves only the communication with AWS Services.